# Mantener datos en formulario al momento de añadir a table ASP CORE

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Vengo con un requerimiento que tengo en mi formulario el cual consiste en añadir los datos que mantengo en mis input a una tabla cosa que hasta el momento con el siguiente codigo en jquery lo realiza sin problema.

```
function AnadirFilaPresup() {
var a = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD").val();
var b = $("#Nom_Pac").val();
var c = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD_ODON").val();
$("#tblTratamiento tbody").append("<tr><td>" + a + "</td><td>" + b + "</td><td>" + c + "</td></tr>");
$("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD").val('');
$("#Nom_Pac").val('');
$("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD_ODON").val('');
```

}

Posteriormente al realizar el guardado, el problema de orita como se ve en la imagen es que al añadir los datos de cada input a mi table, los que no se generan mediante un combo se limpian, como podría mantener el nombre del paciente y código que se mantendrá ya que puede ingresar hasta n filas, debo hacer algun tipo de modificacion en el jquery o añadir algo en mis input de mi formulario.

```
    @page
@model Reg_PresupModel
@{
    var pacpre = Request.Query["pac"];
}

<div class="container-fluid p-4">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">

            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                        @if (Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_ID.Equals(0))
                        {
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Registro de Presupuesto</h3>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Actualización de Presupuesto(S)</h3>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="card rounded">
                            <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                                <div id="header" class="bg-info rounded text-center">
                                    <h2 class="mb-0 t">
                                        @if (Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_ID.Equals(0))
                                        {
                                            <button class="btn btn-block text-light" type="button">
                                                Ingreso de Información
                                            </button>
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            <button class="btn btn-block text-light" type="button">
                                                Actualización de Información
                                            </button>
                                        }

                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="row">

                                        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                            <div class="form-row">
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-12 text-center">
                                                    <label>Nombre de Paciente para Tratamiento:</label>
                                                    <input id="Nom_Pac" value="@pacpre" type="text" readonly placeholder="NOMBRE PACIENTE" class="form-control text-center" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-row">
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                    <label>COD. Presupuesto:</label>
                                                    <input asp-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_COD" type="text" readonly placeholder="CODIGO PRESUPUESTO" class="form-control" />
                                                    <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_COD" class="text-danger"></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                    @if (!Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_ID.Equals(0))
                                                    {
                                                        <label>Profesional:</label>
                                                        @Html.DropDownList("MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_COD_ODON", new SelectList(Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.Odontologo_Lista, "Text", "Text"),
                                     new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "autofocus" })
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        <label>Profesional:</label>
                                                        @Html.DropDownList("MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_COD_ODON", new SelectList(Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.Odontologo_Lista, "Text", "Text"),
             "ESCOGA UN PROFESIONAL", new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "autofocus" })
                                                    }
                                                    <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_COD_ODON" class="text-danger"></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                    @if (!Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_ID.Equals(0))
                                                    {
                                                        <label>Tipo Dentadura:</label>
                                                        @Html.DropDownList("MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_DEN_PAC", new SelectList(Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.Dentadura_Lista, "Text", "Text"),
                                     new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        <label>Tipo Dentadura:</label>
                                                        @Html.DropDownList("MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_DEN_PAC", new SelectList(Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.Dentadura_Lista, "Text", "Text"),
"ESCOGA UN TIPO DE DENTADURA", new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "SeleccionDentadura()" });
                                                    }
                                                    <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_DEN_PAC" class="text-danger"></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-row">

                                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                    @if (!Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_ID.Equals(0))
                                                    {
                                                        <label>Tipo Pieza Dental:</label>
                                                        @Html.DropDownList("MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_PIE_DEN", new SelectList(Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.Pieza_Lista, "Text", "Text"),
                                     new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        <label>Tipo Pieza Dental:</label>
                                                        @Html.DropDownList("MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_PIE_DEN", new SelectList("", "Text", "Text"),
                    "ESCOGA UNA PIEZA DENTAL", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                    }
                                                    <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_PIE_DEN" class="text-danger"></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                    @if (!Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_ID.Equals(0))
                                                    {
                                                        <label>Tipo Tratamiento:</label>
                                                        @Html.DropDownList("MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_TRA_PAC", new SelectList(Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.Tratamiento_Lista, "Text", "Text"),
                                     new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        <label>Tipo Tratamiento:</label>
                                                        @Html.DropDownList("MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_TRA_PAC", new SelectList(Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.Tratamiento_Lista, "Text", "Text"),
             "ESCOGA UN TRATAMIENTO", new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "SeleccionTratamiento()" })
                                                    }
                                                    <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_TRA_PAC" class="text-danger"></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                    <label>Valor Tratamiento:</label>
                                                    <input asp-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_PRE" type="number" readonly class="form-control" />
                                                    <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_PRE" class="text-danger"></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-row">
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                    <label>Porcentaje Dscto. Tratamiento:</label>
                                                    <input asp-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_POR" type="number" onchange="Dscto_Trat_Presup()" class="form-control" />
                                                    <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_POR" class="text-danger"></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                    <label>Descuento Tratamiento:</label>
                                                    <input asp-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_DES" type="number" readonly class="form-control" />
                                                    <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_DES" class="text-danger"></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                    <label>Total Tratamiento:</label>
                                                    <input asp-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_SUB" type="number" readonly class="form-control" />
                                                    <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_SUB" class="text-danger"></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-row">
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                                    @if (!Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_ID.Equals(0))
                                                    {
                                                        <label>Estado Tratamiento:</label>
                                                        <input asp-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_EST_ELI" type="text" readonly placeholder="ESTADO TRATAMIENTO" class="form-control" />
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        <label>Estado Tratamiento:</label>
                                                        <input asp-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_EST_ELI" type="text" readonly value="V" class="form-control" />
                                                    }
                                                    <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_EST_ELI" class="text-danger"></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-row">
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn bg-info btn-block text-light" onclick="AnadirFilaPresup()">+</button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn bg-info btn-block text-light">-</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm col-lg">
                                    <div class="card">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <nav>
                                                <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                                                    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-fee" role="tab" aria-selected="true">PRESUPUESTO</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </nav>
                                            <div class="row text-center"> 
                                                <div class="tab-content table-responsive" id="nav-tabContent">
                                                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-fee" role="tabpanel">
                                                        <table class="table table-striped" id="tblTratamiento">
                                                            <thead class="text-center">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <th>
                                                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_COD)
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th>
                                                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_NOM_PAC)
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th>
                                                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_NOM_ODON)
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th>
                                                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_RUT)
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th>
                                                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_DEN_PAC)
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th>
                                                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_PIE_DEN)
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th>
                                                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_TRA_PAC)
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th>
                                                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_PRE)
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th>
                                                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_POR)
                                                                    </th>
                                                                    <th>
                                                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_SUB)
                                                                    </th>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </thead>
                                                            <tbody >
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-interests" role="tabpanel">


                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <hr />
                                    <div class="container-fluid">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="text-center form-group col-md-4 ">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="text-center form-group col-md-4 ">
                                                @if (Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_ID.Equals(0))
                                                {
                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn bg-info btn-block text-light">Registro</button>
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn bg-info btn-block text-light">Actualizar</button>
                                                }
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="text-center form-group col-md-12 ">
                                                <label class="text-danger">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.ErrorMessage)  </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de una pequeñas validaciones y pruebas así quedaría mi jquery que cumple lo que necesito junto con una pequeña captura de imagen del resultado final.

```
function AnadirFilaPresup() {
var a = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD").val();
var b = $("#Nom_Pac").val();
var c = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_COD_ODON").val();
var cadena = c.substring(5, 20);
var d = $("#Rut_Pac").val();
var e = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC").val();
var f = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").val();
var g = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_TRA_PAC").val();
var h = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_PRE").val();
var i = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_POR").val();
var j = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_DES").val();
var k = $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_SUB").val();
$("#tblTratamiento tbody").append("<tr><td>" + a + "</td><td>" + b + "</td><td>" + cadena + "</td><td>" + d + "</td><td>" + e +
    "</td><td>" + f + "</td><td>" + g + "</td><td>" + h + "</td><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + j + "</td><td>" + k + "</td></tr>");
$("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_DEN_PAC").val('');
$("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_PIE_DEN").val('');
$("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_TRA_PAC").val('');
$("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_PRE").val('0');
$("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_POR").val('0');
$("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_DES").val('0');
$("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_SUB").val('0');
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]